# You are given an array A of N integers. Your task is to find the maximum number of times an odd number is repeated in the array

Tags: python-3.x

You are given an array A of N integers. Your task is to find the maximum number of times an odd number is repeated in the array.

Sample Input:

12
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1

Sample Output:

4

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

c = 0
fc = 0
for i in range(n):
    if arr[i] % 2 != 0:
        temp = arr[i]
        c += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if arr[j] == temp:
                c += 1
            else:
                print(c)
                c = 0
                break
if c > fc:
    fc = c
print(fc)
```

I have tried the above approach, but it returns 6 for the input case

Comment: Does the maximum repeated odd number need to be consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting count in the `else` clause which is wrong since you need to reset count everytime you see a new odd number. Moreover, you need to check if `c > fc` after you have computed `c` everytime, not just in the end.
Here is your code fixed.

```
c = 0
fc = 0
for i in range(n):
    if arr[i] % 2 != 0:
        c = 0
        temp = arr[i]
        c += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if arr[j] == temp:
                c += 1
            else:
                print(c)
                break
    if c > fc:
        fc = c
print(fc)
```

Here is a better approach, which traverses the list of numbers only once.

```
index = 0
maxCount = 0
currCount = 0
while index < len(arr):
    if arr[index]%2 == 1:
        currCount = 0
        currCount += 1
        index += 1
        while index < len(arr) and arr[index]%2 == 1:
            currCount += 1
            index+=1
        if currCount > maxCount:
            maxCount = currCount
    index+=1

print(maxCount)
```